# What do I do to slow down fan?

Tags: fan

I have an Athlon x2 4600 on an Asus M2N32WS Pro mainboard Bios dated 2006.

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 11.10 fan runs constantly. I have run pwmconfig, however, fan still runs at a higher speed than I feel is necessary.

I would like it to only run this fast when it is necessary and be quiet the rest of the time.

Comment: I have the same problem too..

Answer (score 1):

Did you update the BIOS on the motherboard since 2006.There was a nasty power usage regression in the 2.6.3x series kernels as well.

Answer (score 1):

First (as mentioned in another answer) try to check if have the BIOS version and flash it if necessary.

If that doesn't solve the issue, try the latest 3.3.x kernel. The [ACPI support](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTA0NDE) was updated and using that kernel version might improve your hardware situation.

1. Check your current architecture using `uname -a`

   > $ uname -a
   >   Linux savvas-desktop 3.0.0-17-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 8 20:45:39 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

   How to choose package files:

   - *x86-64* then you search for amd64 in the name of the debian package files.
   - *i686* or *i386* then you search for i386 / i686 in the name of the debian package files - without pae.
   - if you see -pae in the kernel version (e.g. 3.0.0-17-generic-pae), then you search for i386 pae in the name of the debian package files.

   You also include the package files that have *all* in their file name instead of i686/i386/amd64.
2. Go to http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/
   and choose the most stable recent version (without *rc* - that means release candidate, not stable). Current stable version is v3.3.1-precise: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.3.1-precise/

   Using the file selection from (1) and "v3.3.1-precise" as the latest stable version, we choose 3 files:

   For amd64:

   - http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.3.1-precise/linux-headers-3.3.1-030301-generic_3.3.1-030301.201204021435_amd64.deb
   - http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.3.1-precise/linux-headers-3.3.1-030301_3.3.1-030301.201204021435_all.deb
   - http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.3.1-precise/linux-image-3.3.1-030301-generic_3.3.1-030301.201204021435_amd64.deb

   For i386:

   - http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.3.1-precise/linux-headers-3.3.1-030301_3.3.1-030301.201204021435_all.deb
   - http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.3.1-precise/linux-headers-3.3.1-030301-generic_3.3.1-030301.201204021435_i386.deb
   - http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.3.1-precise/linux-image-3.3.1-030301-generic_3.3.1-030301.201204021435_i386.deb

   For i386 with pae enabled:

   - http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.3.1-precise/linux-headers-3.3.1-030301-generic-pae_3.3.1-030301.201204021435_i386.deb
   - http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.3.1-precise/linux-headers-3.3.1-030301_3.3.1-030301.201204021435_all.deb
   - http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.3.1-precise/linux-image-3.3.1-030301-generic-pae_3.3.1-030301.201204021435_i386.deb

   You have to download these 3 files and install them one by one by double-clicking on them. If it doesn't allow you to because of dependencies, try one of the other packages and then try the first one again.

   When you install all 3 files successfully, you can reboot and choose the kernel 3.3.x. If you notice any problems, you can reboot, and select some other version. You can also purge/uninstall the packages if you search for linux-image-3.3 and linux-headers-3.3 in a package manager.